# Codeigniter, Database Errror, Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get a value of an attribute from database named "post_id to use somewhere else.

Here is my model code.

```
$copy_query = "SELECT post_id FROM posts order by post_id DESC limit 1"; //query for selecting last post's post_id
$result = $this->db->query($copy_query);    //adding that post_id to the $result variable 

$sub_data = array(
                    'study_education_level' => $this->input->post('sub_education_level'),
                    'tourism_country' => $this->input->post('sub_tourism_country'),
                    'tourism_place_name' => $this->input->post('sub_tourism_placeName'),
                    'post_id' => $result
            );

            $this->db->insert('subcategories',$sub_data);
```

But whenever I run the code it gives me two ERROR.

1. A PHP Error was encountered

   ```
   Severity: 4096

   Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

   Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

   Line Number: 553
   ```

And 
2.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

INSERT INTO `subcategories` (`study_education_level`, `tourism_country`, `tourism_place_name`, `post_id`) VALUES ('Higher Study', '', '', )

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: query() calls never return the actual value you're selecting in the query. they return a RESULT SET, from which you have to fetch a row (usually as an array), and from that array you can get the actual value. so yeah, you're trying to stuff your result set object into an array and the insert it, which means the result object is going to try and get stringified by php.

Comment: You need to do more studying on Codeigniter. Read this: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

Btw Ive solve the problem :)

```
$result = $this->db->query($copy_query);    //adding that post_id to the variable   
            if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                    foreach ($result->result() as $row)
                    {
                            $post_id_plz =  $row->post_id;
                    }
            }
```